# In order to predict after training on Standardized data, do I need the StandardScaler as well?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

Is the `scaler` saved inside the `model.keras` file or I need to separately save it?

I want to train an neural network, save it, and then send it to a co-worker that will do the predictions on data that I do not have access to.  Is it enough to just send the `.keras` file or I also need to send the `scaler`?

Before training I Standardized the data

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

after the NN is trained I save it

```
model.save(".../X.keras")
```

Now I want to load it and predict on new data (or the test data)

```
ann = load_model(".../X.keras")
```

And evaluate the model using

```
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
y_predict_NN = ann.predict(X_test_scaled)
```

So how I get the scaler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save and restore the scaler independently of the keras model - the scaler is from scikit-learn. This is easier done than said:

```
from joblib import dump, load

# in the code, once the scaler is fitted
dump(scaler, 'filename.joblib')
```

...

```
 # in the test code, load the fitted scaler, can be different file, etc

new_scaler  = load('filename.joblib')
```

Comment: Thanks!  is there an alternative option that use `inverse_transform()` ?  
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform

Comment: inverse_transform is used to get back to original unscaled data starting with scaled data. Not sure how applicable it would be in this case. You could of course use methods on the StandardScaler to get the mean and standard deviation, and apply these manually on the untransformed test data.